# Prepend Objects to Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

**Hey Guys,**

i have a small question regarding JavaScript Objects.
I have the following Object in JavaScript:

```
var CONFIG = {
    MAIN_URL: 'http://www.test.us',
    MAIN_COLOR: '#fff'
}
```

now i want to declare an object with another object prefixed:

```
var CONFIG = {
    MAIN_URL: 'http://www.test.us',
    LOGIN_URL: MAIN_URL+'/login', // <- this one!
    MAIN_COLOR: '#fff'
}
```

how do i do that?
I have tried with this.MAIN_URL, CONFIG[MAIN_URL], CONFIG.MAIN_URL - but nothing works?!?!

Thanks,
Sascha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that in an object initializer. Instead, do something like this:

```
var CONFIG = {};
CONFIG.MAIN_URL = 'http://www.test.us';
CONFIG.LOGIN_URL = CONFIG.MAIN_URL+'/login'; // <- this one!
CONFIG.MAIN_COLOR = '#fff';
```

Comment: i prefer your method... i like :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
var CONFIG = new function() {
    this.MAIN_URL = 'http://www.test.us',
    this.LOGIN_URL = this.MAIN_URL+'/login', // <- this one!
    this.MAIN_COLOR = '#fff'
};
```

Comment: Hi Esailija, thanks for the fast response. This works :-) Amazing. Thanks again!

Comment: @codeworxx: It works, but it creates a lot more stuff than you need. Just `var CONFIG = {}; CONFIG.MAIN_URL = ...;` and such is no more verbose, and avoids unnecessarily creating and running functions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if verbosity is a concern, then you can alias `this` to something at the top of function, which results in a better minification as well and the alias won't leak into current scope (global it seems)

Comment: @Esailija Ew. I think that just makes the problem worse.

Comment: okay, thanks esailija, but i prefer kendalls method...